# how to use adoptedStyleSheets to append multiple stylesheets

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple style blocks. How do I use adopted style sheets to append the multiple style sheets? For example, I have

```
.test {
   background-color: #fff;
}
.wow {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

and then another stored in another variable

```
.test2 {
   background-color: #fff;
}
.wow2 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Should I be calling replaceSync twice?

Here's what I tried

```
const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
sheet.replaceSync(styles1);

sheet.insertRule(styles2);

document.adoptedStyleSheets = [...document.adoptedStyleSheets, sheet];
```

Comment: I would say try posting a [mcve] that includes the javascript that you are using

Answer (score 0):

Since adoptedStyleSheets property is an array of CSSStyleSheet, just separate the styles like this:

```
import firstcss from '../css/firstcss.css' assert { type: 'css' };
import secondcss from '../css/secondcss.css' assert { type: 'css' };

document.adoptedStyleSheets = [firstcss, secondcss];
```